# sympy "Invalid limits given" when plotting hyperbolic integral

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to do some calculations in sympy but keep getting an "Invalid limits given" error when I try and plot my function.  I'm new to python and sympy so I'm sure it's an obvious mistake but I just cant understand how the limits are invalid.

```
import sympy

x = sympy.symbols('x')
min_x, max_x = -6.0, 6.0

func = x * sympy.integrate(x * sympy.tanh(x), (x, min_x, max_x))

p = sympy.plot(func)
```

Comment: I think the confusion is coming from the fact that you're trying to use `x` with two different meanings: it's both a free variable of `func` and the dependent variable of the integral. Think about what you're writing mathematically. Would it make sense to write `f(x) = x * \int_a^b g(x) dx`?

Comment: When I add a secondary symbol I get UserWarning: The evaluation of the expression is problematic. We are trying a failback method that may still work. Please report this as a bug.
  return self.__call__(args)

Answer (score 0):

In a few words, the plotting module converts the symbolic expression to a numerical function, evaluates it and create the plot. However, the current plotting module is using out-of-date code to convert the symbolic expression to a numerical function. That error simply means that the plotting module can't plot the expression.

You can plot your expression in two different ways. The first: convert the symbolic expression to a numerical function, use numpy and matplotlib:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
f = sympy.lambdify(x, func)
plt.figure()
xx = np.linspace(-10, 10)
yy = f(xx)
plt.plot(xx, yy)
```

The second one: you install the new and more advanced plotting module, [Sympy Plot Backend](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html). Then:

```py
from spb import *
plot(func)
```